# Sql server statement ordering ASC

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am currently try to sort date in ASC. If i used ASC it will sort the data will null date than the next date.

So i do something like this
Select * from tblUser
order by LastLogin and it will display the following

```
Name             LastLogin 
1. Peter         NULL
2. Brian         2013-03-14
3. Jack          2013-03-15
```

But i want to return something this and please advise i can achieve this

```
1. Brian         2013-03-14
2. Jack          2013-03-15
3. Peter         NULL
```

Comment: My apology Damien. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
ORDER   BY CASE WHEN lastlogin IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, lastlogin
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acce2/2)

Comment: That works; Also if you are on SQL Server 2012 you can use: `ORDER BY LastLogin ASC NULLS LAST`

Comment: Ah, I figured; We don't use 2012 yet... I've been itching to use that so it was ready and loaded ;)